# Retrieve a config-key from a different config-file depending on the controller or view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I had an ASP.NET WebForms project with the following structure:

- Page1 (Folder)

  - Default.aspx
  - Default.aspx.cs
  - web.config (containing key ProductId = 111)
- Page2 (Folder)

  - Default.aspx
  - Default.aspx.cs
  - web.config (containing key ProductId = 222)
- Page3 (Folder)

  - Default.aspx
  - Default.aspx.cs
  - web.config (containing key ProductId = 333)
- web.config (containing various keys for common usage

This way I was able to obtain a different value for the config key "ProductId" depending on the Default.aspx.cs file I was requesting it from.

Now I'd like to reproduce the same behavior in an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web Application (this means obtain a different value depending on the Controller or View where I'm requesting the config key from). Is this somehow possible?

As much as I know configuration must be built in the Startup.cs (e.g. using json files). Does ASP.NET Core provide any possibility to have the configuration as flexible as it was in WebForms?
Of course I could also store the keys/values in a database or in a C# class with constants for each controller/view, but I'd like to keep them in the config.

Comment: Have u tried? I thought it should be the same as WebForms&MVCForms
https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides

Comment: @DanielB I haven't tried so far since I assumed that the only way would be to explicitly declare all desired files to be used as source for the configuration in the Startup.cs

Comment: + since im curious to know.

Comment: @DanielB it's not. .NET Core's configuration is completely different and *doesn't* have any default configuration files. Different parts can come from *completely* different sources like json files, environment variables, databasaes

Comment: @Dario what you were doing was *not* loading different keys per controller/page. You were overriding the configuration for different folders, incidentally resulting in a different value per page. This wouldn't work in MVC projects where all controllers are typically placed on the same folder and are *not* supposed to depend on their location.

Comment: @Dario Besides, you don't need it. An MVC controller can receive parameters from the URL itself. Instead of using multiple folders you can define a route that uses the `Page1` etc part as a parameter to a *single* controller. For example, the URL `http://mysite/Products/Cars` would call the `Index(string id)` action of `ProductsController` with the parameter `Cars`. You could use the value as-is or map it to something else in the controller itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes but for my use case I need to keep these value "invisible" to the end users, so the route-data isn't a suitable place.